# EIGRP unequal load balancing, variance command

Tags: cisco, routing, protocol-theory, eigrp

Is correct to say that the value inserted in the variance command, lets say the value of "2" on a route that has a cost of, lets say "100", will unequally load balance all routes up to a cost of 200 ?

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is correct to say that the value inserted in the variance command,
>   lets say the value of "2" on a route that has a cost of, lets say
>   "100", will unequally load balance all routes up to a cost of 200 ?

No. The `variance` command doesn't change the feasibility condition; it changes the minimum metric allowed. Any paths must still meet the feasibility condition before they are considered for balancing with the `variance` command.

In other words, a path must have a feasible successor in order for EIGRP to consider sending traffic over that path. See the portion I have highlighted in the document below.

[How Does Unequal Cost Path Load Balancing (Variance) Work in IGRP and EIGRP?](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/enhanced-interior-gateway-routing-protocol-eigrp/13677-19.html)

> ### Network Diagram
>
> [image]
>
> ### Variance
>
> This section provides an example. In the network diagram, there are
>   three ways to get to Network X:
>
> - E-B-A with a metric of 30
> - E-C-A with a metric of 20
> - E-D-A with a metric of 45
>
> Router E chooses the path E-C-A with a metric of 20 because 20 is
>   better than 30 and 45. In order to instruct EIGRP to select the path
>   E-B-A as well, configure variance with a multiplier of 2:
>
> ```
> router eigrp 1
> network x.x.x.x
> variance 2
> ```
>
> This configuration increases the minimum metric to 40 (2 * 20 = 40).
>   EIGRP includes all routes that have a metric of less than or equal to
>   40 and satisfy the feasibility condition. In the configuration in this
>   section, EIGRP now uses two paths to get to Network X, E-C-A and
>   E-B-A, because both paths have a metric of under 40. EIGRP does not
>   use path E-D-A because that path has a metric of 45, which is not less
>   than the value of the minimum metric of 40, because of the variance
>   configuration. ***Also, the reported distance of neighbor D is 25,
>   which is greater than the feasible distance (FD) of 20 through C. This
>   means that, even if variance is set to 3, the E-D-A path is not
>   selected for load balancing because Router D is not a feasible
>   successor.***
>
> **Note:** For more information on variance, refer to [Troubleshooting EIGRP Variance Command](https://supportforums.cisco.com/docs/DOC-23674).

Answer (score 0):

The variance command inserted in EIGRP used to adjust metric for EIGRP  accordinglly.

EIGRP by default supports equals and unequal cost load balancing . Variances command is used to adjust unequal cost loading balancing .